# I need help making a header background image scalable

Tags: html, css, image

Hi as the title says i need to make the background image for the header scalable so that you will still be able to see the image on any device as well as being able to read the text, is this possible? i'm currently working on pogl.co/ and this is where it needs to be changed. i need it to be like www.blacksmithsarms.com/

any help is much appriciated

thanks
Josh

edit: this is what i have at the minute

```
.bill-board{
background: url(../img/backgrounds/rig.jpg) no-repeat;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

i want it to be scalable like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tITED.jpg

Comment: I do not see your problem. Can you explain a bit more briefly what you are after?

Comment: Links are not working for me

Comment: Do you just need `background-size: cover;` ...?

Comment: hi what i'm looking for is this
http://imgur.com/UgREGpT,uwHCj58

as you can the image gets smaller as the window gets smaller, thats what i'm looking for. what i ahve at the minute is

.bill-board{
  background: url(../img/backgrounds/rig.jpg) no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

I have tried using cover but that doesn't keep the image on smaller screens. i'm thinking maybe the image i'm using is too big?

Comment: background-size: contain;

Comment: using contain sort of works but makes the image tiny. i think i'm right in thinking that it's the image that's causing it

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Instead of using background image use direct `img` tag.

```
 <div class="bill-board">
    <img src="img/backgrounds/rig.jpg"/>
 </div>
```

style

```
.bill-board img{
  height:auto;
}
```

Comment: I think width should be 100% too